# How can I create a custom rule set for php-cs-fixer?

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

How to create custom ruleset to be run by `fix` command with option `--rules=@custom`?

Like `@PSR1`, `@PSR2`, `@Symfony`, `@PHP56Migration`, `@PHP70Migration`, `@PHP71Migration` are made.

Php-cs-fixer version: 2.2.3

Only by inserting into vendor code -`vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/src/RuleSet.php`:

```
private $setDefinitions = array(
        '@custom' => [
        'some_custom_fixer` => true,
        ]
)
```

Works as I expect, but `RuleSet` is `final class`. Is there a way to override or extend the `setDefinitions` when using custom config `.php_cs`?

Comment: Why not simplify list specific fixers? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Like that: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/pull/2884

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there is no way to register custom ruleset how you register custom fixer.
Although that, we were already thinking that it would be nice to introduce it, yet it is not a prio on our todo list.
Feel free to write proposal how it shall be handled, and PR after initial discussion.
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/

Answer (score 3):

In the meanwhile, create your own configuration instead and share it across projects.

For example:

- [refinery29/php-cs-fixer-config](https://github.com/refinery29/php-cs-fixer-config)
- [ergebnis/php-cs-fixer-config](https://github.com/ergebnis/php-cs-fixer-config)

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://cs.symfony.com/doc/custom_rules.html) homepage that says that the following should work:

```
<?php
// ...
return (new PhpCsFixer\Config())
    // ...
    ->registerCustomFixers([
        new CustomerFixer1(),
        new CustomerFixer2(),
    ])
    ->setRules([
        // ...
        'YourVendorName/custome_rule' => true,
        'YourVendorName/custome_rule_2' => true,
    ])
;
```

Personally I don't understand what to put in 'YourVendorName'...